# Возможно ли с помощью qsort() отсортировать массив структур по полю структуры

Tags: c

Есть определенная структура:

```
typedef struct Bus_Info
{
   char b_n[9];
   char name[15];
   char way[4];
   int parking;
   int lesion;
} bus_Info;
```

И есть массив данных структур. Всю информацию для заполнения, получаем с файла. Надо его остортировать по полю `b_n`. Нагуглил, что можно делать сортировку массивов с помощью `qsort()` Любопытно можно ли осуществить в данном случае сортировку таким способом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно сортировать что угодно. Например, в Вашем случае кусок кода будет примерно таким. Разумеется, я подозреваю, что `b_n` - это строки, и сравниваю их как строки.

```
bus_Info x[10];

int sf (const void *a, const void *b) {
  return strcmp (((bus_Info*)a)->b_n, ((bus_Info*)b)->b_n);
}

int main () {
  qsort (x, 10, sizeof(x[0]), sf);  
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно. Если вы хотите хотите использовать [`qsort()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/), то вам нужна функция компаратор (4й аргумент функции `qsort()` как раз принимает указатель на функцию компаратор), где можно описать логику сравнения.

Также существует еще один способ - использовать [`std::sort()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/), где 3м аргументом можно использовать лямбду. Благодаря ей код будет лаконичнее.

Comment: `qsort()` принимает 4 аргумента. 4-й - это компаратор, а 3-й - размер структуры.

Comment: @Zealint благодарю! Поправил ответ